# VB6 can't toggle bookmark while debugging

Tags: vb6, bookmarks

I can toggle an bookmark in code when the project isn't running. But when it is, the toggle bookmark button in toolbar is disabled. Only next/prev. bookmark buttons works. Doesn't matter if it's running or paused.

The service pack 6 is installed. I have some add-ins and components installed and loaded too: "Component Services Add-In for VB 5.0/6.0", "Mz-Tools 3.0", "MouseWheel Fix" and "BookmarkSave VB6 addin".

Does anyone already saw this?

Answer (score 2):

The "BookmarkSave VB6" addin disables the button on runtime.

Removing / disabling it fixes the problem.